# Git Push Fails with RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053

Tags: git, curl, github, push

Full list of info

```
Counting objects: 1945, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1935/1935), done.
rror: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (1945/1945), 3.15 GiB | 1.21 MiB/s, done.
Total 1945 (delta 231), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

As far as I can tell, there is no file larger than 150MB, using the latest Git version. I've been able to push with no issue up until I added lots of new assets to my project (around 3GB worth) and now I get this.

What I have tried is increasing the `postBuffer` for both `http` and `https` to `2097152000`

I should also note that I did originally have a large zip file that was not ignored (400MB) but I deleted it and made a new commit, however, this may not have been the proper way to have gotten rid of this, as I guess it will still try to push it out since the commit before the latest had it?

Comment: Please format your error message to be readable (as code, instead of blockquote).

Answer (score 5):

According to [github's help page](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/) max size per file is 100MB, and up to 1GB total for your repo.

Are you using [LFS](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/)?

Comment: I have installed LFS but it seems its only for pushing out large files (greater than 150MB) which I currently don't have any large file I'm trying to push out. My github repo is already like 6GB, further research seems to indicate there is no limit to the repo size unless that 1GB implies a push limit of 1GB?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a hard limit, it says `If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from GitHub Support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down.`. Try to split your files over multiple commits, or tracking files with LFS

Comment: Uploading it all at once may be too heavy of a task

Comment: Looking into the beast and easiest way to split the commits.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error, after cloning fresh from the upstream master,  then I was pushing to my fork but had not kept my fork's master up to date with the upstream master. The different between the fork's master and what the new clone's upstream master had were too different.

The fix was to blow away my fork (copy all existing branches to my local computer so I don't loose any current work), refork, clone from my fork (not upstream), make changes on local computer, and push back to fork.