# One of the users can't push to gitlab if the commit contains a file over 200kb

Tags: git, gitlab

We use a self-managed Gitlab. One of my colleagues can't push over https or ssh if the commit contains a new image file over 200kb while others can succeed in doing the same push. He can also succeed if the commit does not contain such new images over 200kb. We use LDAP accounts on Gitlab and our accounts have the same access rights in this repository. We work on Mac. Git LFS is not used. The push size limit is not set. His account and computer are not restricted by the IT department.

The error message says, with ssh:

```
packet_write_poll: Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Permission denied
fatal: the remote end hung unexpectedly
```

and with https:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 13
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Note that it's not about public key.

We've tried `dtrace` and the log has errors:

```
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2175 (ID 945: syscall::read_nocancel:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2175 (ID 159: syscall::read:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2175 (ID 557: syscall::sysctl:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
```

The workaround is that the other colleagues help commit and push such new files, but it's a bit frustrating.

So far, we have reinstalled Git and it doesn't work either. We are planning to reinstall the system in the coming holidays and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: That's ... bizarre. The "connection ... Permission denied" suggests that there's some ssh or network level barrier to connecting to the ssh port (port 22), but this would never be clever enough to trigger based on *file* size. Moreover, current public Git has no occurrence of the string `packet_write_poll` in it anywhere.

Comment: Just check the files <git_installPath>\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config ( for windows ), ~/.ssh/config (for linux) and change the **ServerAliveInterval** at client side.

Comment: @torek yes, quite bizarre. First time to encounter this error. And I updated the question with the https error message.

Comment: @ankidaemon thanks for your comment. I added `ServerAliveInterval 15` to `~/.ssh/config` but got the same error. I updated the question with https error message.

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790394/git-push-fails-with-rpc-failed-curl-55-ssl-write-returned-syscall-errno-10) of any help, 2nd talks abt fork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution. The problem was caused by the permission access, you can ask the operation engineer in your company, remember that send him or her your MAC address to location your computer. Asking the operation engineer to change the group of your computer in your company. My computer was located to a wrong group before so that I losed lots of permissions in the company's inner Net including pushing picture to gitlab, updating test package to test server and so on.

Hope that will help you!

Comment: Thank you very much! It's the same cause.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely hitting a push limit for this particular repository, in the Push Rules settings under repository ( settings/repository ), set the max file limit to 5 MB or whatever size you like. Setting it to 0 (zero) will disable push limit checking.

Comment: lenik, thanks for your answer. I found `Settings-General-Account and limit-Maximum push size` in Admin area. Is this what you refer to? The size it not set, just empty. In the single repository's Setting area, I can't find Push Rules or anything like Push size limit. The trouble I can't figure out is that only one of us has the problem. We have the same access rights in the same repository. If the push limit works, why does it affect only one person?

Comment: @ElpieKay I'm sorry, I'm not working for gitlab, I'm just using it sometimes. though it's not an answer to the original question, but it might be a good idea to install `git lfs`, and put all large files there (binaries). besides that I don't know why only one person is affected or what the real reason could be.